# hibernate many to one mapping, should I insert this way?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

Let's say we have two tables, `user` and `domain`. User may have one Domain, one Domain may be for many users. So we will do unidirectional many to one:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DOMAIN")
public class Domain implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "DOMAIN_ID")
    private Integer domainId;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String domainName;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "\"USER\"")
public class User implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "USER_SEQ")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "USER_SEQ", strategy = "sequence", parameters = @Parameter(name = "sequence", value = "SEQ_USER_ID"))
    @Column(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false)
    private Long userId;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "DOMAIN_ID")
    @ForeignKey(name = "DOMAIN_ID")
    private Domain domain;
}
```

`Domain` table is something unchangable, dictionary. While `User` is editable table.

I'm creating a basic form where user selects domain in which new user will be created. Lets say that my controller received those data:

```
Integer domainId = 1;
String firstName = "aaa";
```

So I'm creating new user:

```
User newUser = new User();
newUser.setFirstName( firstName );
```

Now comes my question, should I do this way?

```
Domain domain = somthingThatWillFetchObjectFromDb.getDomain( domainId );
newUser.setDomain( domain );
//save user
```

THis will generate additional select, to fetch domain. Of course I can use `Integer domainId` instead of POJO, but that's not ORM. So once again the question, is this the way it should be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's what you should do. If you don't want to actually load the domain information from the database, use the strangely named `Session.load()` method instead of the `Session.get()` method. If the domain is not already loaded into the session, `Session.load()` will simply return you an unitialized entity proxy for the domain (just like if you had loaded some entity with a lazy association to the domain), without hitting the database.

That said, if domain is unchangeable, why do you set `@Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)` on the domain field? This means that every time you're merging or updating a user, the domain will also be merged or updated. And even worse: if you delete a user, the domain will also be deleted (which of course will lead to an exception if other users are referencing the same domain).

Comment: Of course it shouldn't be there, my mistake when pasting :) Both objects are much bigger then here

Answer (score 1):

Yes. To save a child Entity like `User`, you need to set the parent Entity i.e. `Domain` Entity in it.

One otherway is to define bidirectional mapping(OneToMany) in parent Entity ie. Domain, load the `Domain`, add one or more `User` object in `Domain` and save `Domain` Entity only e.g.

`Domain` Entity:

```
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "domain")
  List<User> users = null;

  public List<User> getUsers(){
     return this.users;
  }

  public void setUsers(List<User> user){
     this.users = users;
  }

  public void addUser(User user){
     user.setDomain(this);//set the parent entity
     if(this.users==null){
        this.users = new ArrayList<User>();
     }
     this.user.add(user);
  }
```

Then to save users:

```
   User user1 = new User();
   ......
   User user2 = new User();
   ......
   Domain domain = loadDomain();//<- use actual method to load the domain
   //< add all the users to be saved at once
   domain.addUser(user1); 
   domain.addUser(user2);
   //save parent entity i.e. domain
   saveDomain(domain);//use actual method to save the entity
```