# How to insert ManyToOne relationship record in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I have two classes as following,

**Human.java**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Human implements Serializable {

   private long id;
   private String name;
    ....
}
```

**Student.java**

```
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
public class Student extends MyFactories {

    private List<Know> KnowList;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public List<Know> getKnowlist() {
        return knowlist;
    }

    public void setKnowlist(List<Know> KnowList) {
        return Knowlist;
    }
}
```

**Know.java**

```
@Entity
public class Know implements Serializable {

    private long id;
    private Human hu;
    private Student st;

    ....

    @ManyToOne 
    public Person getHu() {
        return hu;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    public Client getSt() {
        return st;
    }

    ....  setters .....
}
```

**Code**

```
            Know kw = new Know();
            kw.setSt(studentObject);
            kw.setHu(humanObject);
            session.save(kw);
            tx.commit();
```

I am able to insert into Know table but hibernate does not insert any record to student_know table which it has created.

I have found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746499/how-to-resolve-failed-to-lazily-initialize-a-collection-of-role-exception) but it says I need to use that method if I always want to retrieve all the records. Which I do not (at times, I may just need to retrieve the student class not list of its know)

```
    System.out.println(this.student.getKnowList().size());
```

When I try to access the list it runs into following exception.

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.myproject.Student.knowList, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

Comment: have you looked at this ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13199045/hibernate-many-to-one-mapping-should-i-insert-this-way

Comment: @CPU100 thanks but I have the factory and myfactories objects but not sure how to connect product table to myfactories and factory objects

Comment: Student extends MyFactories? the getter `Client getSt()` and the variable `Student st` can your example code realy work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use session.Update(studentObject) as well, to insert a row into student_know table.

Please also be aware that access to a lazy association outside of the context of an open Hibernate session will result in an exception. [Link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-lazy)

Answer (score 2):

for select case change that `@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` to  `@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)` so you can get data inside it's list.

and for the insert i need your clarification about where is your relation or getter setter of the `private Factory fac;`?

you should have at least something like this :

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "YOUR_FACTORY_ID_COLUMN")
private Factory fac;

public Factory getFac(){
    return fac;
}

public void setFac(Factory fac){
    this.fac=fac;
}
```

and did factory have any id?

Comment: factory is inheriting its id from myfactories, I have included all the getter and setters, I do not want it to load all the products every time it is loading factory object as they are a lot.

Comment: they will only loading all product inside that factory, your exception is because you didn't get the object(product) when you in a state that can't get the session. so the only way is to load it before you going to move this object to session-less state(maybe you send this Factory to client and try to get its Product).

Comment: it runs into this error EVERE: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.myproject.Know column: id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

Comment: that's already a different problem, [see this article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-2008/jw-08-hibernate-annotations.html) for how to create **simple persistent class**. or post another question if you have difficulty creating those standard persistent class.

Comment: but the first problem still exists

Comment: i edit the answer(add cascade), now try that, and if that didnt work post your edited code here(don't forget to read link i mentioned before to create id auto generated).

Comment: thanks but J888 posted the answer, the problem was that I was not updating the student table. thanks anyway

Comment: you are welcome, however, you can still use cascade though if you want to save/edit/delete list without having another update.